# Odoo - Give a warning when editing some field with empty value

Tags: python, odoo, edit

I want to add an entry to the suppliers table if one creates a new or edits a product. Each product must have a supplier.
If a supplier is not selected, system must give a warning “You should fill in the supplier details, at least one.”

Here is my code:

```
class warning_supplier(models.Model):
_inherit = 'product.template'

@api.multi
def write(self, vals):
    res = super(warning_supplier, self).write(vals)
    supplier_id = self.env['res.partner'].search([('name','=','No Supplier')])
    for this in self:
        seller_ids = this.seller_ids
        if len(seller_ids)==0:
            raise Warning('You should fill in the supplier details, at least one.')
    return res
```

When I create products, the code runs correctly.

But when I edit a product & remove the selected supplier, it does not work any more.

Can someone pinpoint the error to me? Thanks!

---

Edit: Fixed by using constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add python constraint, that will execute when given field has been modified.

```
class product_template(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.template'

    @api.multi
    @api.constrains('seller_ids')
    def onchange_seller(self):
        for record in self :
            if not record.seller_ids :
                raise ValidationError("You should fill in the supplier details, at least one.")
        return
```

For more information about constrains : [click here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#module-odoo.api)

Comment: When I add this, I can't create products properly now. Even when I add the supplier, the warning showing up.

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating product `create` function is called, and on edit always `write` function.

In create you should check `vals` parameter and if it doesn't meet the requirements you should warn user to correct it and after that edit actual record.

Try something like this

```
# For example boolean
if vals["myBoolean"] == False:
    raise Warning('myBoolean should be true always!')
```

Comment: I'm sorry I still didn't really understand what do you mean by that. But when I tried to replace my [ if len(seller_ids)==0: ] to [ if vals['seller_ids']==False: ], my code become didn't work.

Comment: If user didn't fill `seller_ids` then this attribute won't be in `vals`, it will be available only if user fills `seller_ids` or changes it. You can debug to see full image